Will upgrading my personal account to a Google Workspace account increase the Apps Script data limit?
I've had no issues with the dataset allowances when using Apps Script until last night, when I got the execution error:
"Logging output too large. Truncating output."
If I upgrade my personal account to a Google Workspace account. Would it allow my Apps Script to be able to use a much larger dataset? My data set is stored in Google Sheets and has 60 columns and just under 200 rows
Tried adjusting the code to allow full data reading, added error handling and also checked the sheet for any blank cells

That's not really an error it's just telling you that the output to the execution log has been truncated.  If you wish see it in it's entirety you can direct it into a textarea.

If you use the results from Wicket's search results, can you get a more detailed error?

Using a Google Workspace account will not solve the "error" referred to. For details about Google Apps Script quotas, see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quotas.
To learn about logging in Apps Script see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging
Searching "Logging output too large. Truncating output."  here has returned 15 results to me. Do the same yourself and take a look at the results; you might get helpful ideas about how this could be handled in your situation.
